# Express routing not working anymore after update

Tags: node.js, express

After a year passed by i wanted to do some upgrades to my application but the routing doesn't work anymore. `express` is marked with `*` inside my `package.json` but i didn't found any kind of breaking changes the last 12 month.

In any case there must be sth. broken with the routing. The routes directly inside my `app.js` are working fine but the routes outside (here for example the `routes/users.js` are not working (i'm getting 404).

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const users = require('./routes/user/users');

//CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

//Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Importing Authentication
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Setting up Routes
app.use('/users', users);

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
    if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
        
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

//Calling Index-Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Ungültige Route!');
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

//Run server with nodemon
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

`users.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Registrierung eines neuen Benutzers
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log('GOT REQUEST');
    console.log(req.body);
});

...
...
...

module.exports = router;
```

So posting with Postman to the route `http://localhost:3000/users/register` with username and password inside request body only return:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /users/register</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

if i add the following code directly to my `app.js` that explicit route works. It looks like there is a problem in loading the routes from the routing files.

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var htmlData = 'Hello:' + username;
    res.send(htmlData);
    console.log(htmlData);
 });
```

Comment: above code works for me (yanked out the passport part). you will have to provide a minimal example, that is not working.

Comment: wow @madflow that was a good tip... i removed all the passport stuff from app.js and everything is working... what the hell, need to check this, seems like there were some changes in passport.

Comment: Hm, can't find any kind of breaking changes in passport right now, if someone still has another idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this section:

```
//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

because it was handled before the `//Setting up Routes` section. When the code goes after that section, everything is working, also with the new versions of passport and passport-jwt